# Please help me, I dont know where is a problem

Tags: c#

While I solving the task a problem occurred

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, 2, 3));
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 3, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(1, -2, -3));
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(5, 2, 1));
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(4, 3, 2));
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 4, 5));

        // А в этих случаях решение существует: (should be ...НЕ существует)
        // There are NO sulutions in these cases  
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) != "Impossible");
        Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) != "Impossible");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        if (a==0)
        {
            return "Impossible";
        }
        else
        {
            var x = -(b / (2.0 * a));
            return (x).ToString(); // string representation
        }
    }
}
}
```

Everything is correct except the last two lines:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5s42.png

The **last two lines** must be `"True"`. But I don't know why it's `"False"`.

Comment: Well, whenever `a == 0` you'll get `"Impossible"`, the last case is `GetMinX(0, 0, 2)` where `a == 0` finally for `"Impossible" != "Impossible"` you have `False`

Comment: Since there is no problem statement here, I believe this is off-topic. In particular, the title is nothing more than "halp me" pleading, which is not a useful summary of the problem. **Please always use useful titles**.

Comment: Please make an effort to **edit the question** and give it a meaningful title. I would recommend adding more explanation of the problem in the body too. We can then look at reopening the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) != "Impossible");
    Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) != "Impossible");
```

GetMinX returns "Impossible" for those two lines. Which is NOT unequal "Impossible", thus False

What you probably want to do is

```
Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) == "Impossible");
Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) == "Impossible");
```

Answer (score 0):

Time to **reverse engineering**; my crystal orb says that the *initial problem* is:

> Having a polynom `y(x) = a * x^2 + b * x + c`
>
> Return `x` where `y` reaches its **minimum**.

Let's extract *math* routine:

```
 private static double GetMinXValue(double a, double b, double c) {
   if (0 == a) { // degenarted acses  
      if (0 == b)
          return double.Nan; // y = c; all x will do; we can return Nan (no solutions) 
      else if (b > 0) // y = b * x + c
          return double.NegativeInfinity;
      else 
          return double.PositiveInfinity;
   }
   else 
      return -b / (2.0 * a); 
 }
```

Time to implement *UI* (`string` represnetation):

```
 private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c) {
   double min = GetMinXValue(a, b, c);

   return double.IsNan(min) || double.IsInfinity(min)
     ? "Impossible"
     : min.ToString();    
 }
```

Test:

```
 Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(4, 3, 2));
 Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 4, 5));

 // А в этих случаях решение НЕ существует: 
 // There are NO sulutions in these cases  
 Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 2) == "Impossible"); // "True": there's no solution
 Console.WriteLine(GetMinX(0, 0, 0) == "Impossible");
```

Comment: Thank you all guys.You're realy cool ^_^